# SQL Datatable DateTime update

Tags: c#, sql, date, datetime

So, my problem is very complicated and hard to explain.
I have a data Table (SQL) Named "Members" With column "Lengh". 
So i want, each time i start the program to check if there is Lengh that is lower than current date time and Chance the column "Status" to Expired. It works fine if i have just 1 row in the table, but if i have more it changes only 1 row. How do i do it to change ALL the rows where the "Lengh" is lower than current Date Time?

```
InitializeComponent();
        SqlDataAdapter dt = new SqlDataAdapter("Select Lengh From Members",con);
        DataTable adt = new DataTable();
        dt.Fill(adt);
        DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
        DateTime chip = (DateTime)adt.Rows[0][0];
        if (now>chip)
        {
            SqlDataAdapter dt2 = new SqlDataAdapter("Select [Reconizing ID] From Members Where [Lengh]='" + chip + "'", con);
            DataTable adt2 = new DataTable();
            dt2.Fill(adt2);
            string kd = "Update Members Set Status='" + "Expired" + "' Where [Reconizing ID]='" + adt2.Rows[0][0] + "'";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(kd,con);
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
        }
```

if i do infinite loop, the program crashes before it starts.

Comment: Length lower than current date? Seems like a very odd condition.

Comment: It says `Lengh`... not sure if a typo, or a foreign language...

Comment: And to the poster: you need to use loops. Probably both tables `adt` and `adt2` have multiple rows, but you always take only the first row (`adt.Rows[0]`) and from that the first column (`adt.Rows[0][0]`). Same for `adt2`.

Comment: You should always use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/). This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

Comment: Use [`using` statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your connection, command and adapter automatically instead of calling `Close` or `Dispose` methods manually.

Comment: I know that it is open for Injection attacks, i am not releasing it or something, im doing a project for myself.. To get better in coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use pure sql solution for this.
The sql statement to update all the cases at once would look like below.

```
UPDATE MEMBERS SET STATUS = 'Expired' WHERE LENGH < ?
```

To this sql statement, you need to bind (supply) current time `now = DateTime.Now` as input. In single execution, this will update all the rows in the table where length is less than current time.

In case if you do not wish to supply current date time from application , then your query can be even more simple

```
UPDATE MEMBERS SET STATUS = 'Expired' WHERE LENGH < sysdate
```

Of, course this assumes that `LENGH` is date type column in database.

Note 1: In case if you are expecting large number of rows (millions) then consider building an index on `Lengh` column for better performance of query.

Note 2: Some application and database work in multiple timezones or at times there will be time difference between application server and database server. Passing date-time from application code is good coding practice in my opinion.

Comment: Thanks, i didn't knew i am allowed to do that.. I thought it will give me error.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you do it in just one query? Something like:

```
string query="UPDATE Members SET Status='Expired' WHERE @now>Lengh";
SqlCommand cmd= new SqlCommand(query,con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@now",DateTime.Now);
con.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
```

Comment: I have tried and it gives me Convertion error or something like this.. And what does the @now means?

Comment: Btw, it works, thx alot.. the @now means it will use DateTime now?

Comment: Please give the exact error it throws. And to know what `@now` means, see [this](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/268104-the-right-way-to-query-a-database-parameterizing-your-sql-queries/) for example.The `@now` is a parameter, and gets substituted by the value you want in `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@now",DateTime.Now);`

Answer (score 0):

Considering your *Length* column to be of *DateTime* type, you can use following query to update the column in one go

```
UPDATE Members SET Status ='Expired' WHERE Length < GETDATE()
```